# Loading a form dynamically

Tags: vb.net, forms, load, parameter-passing

I have a to-do list in 1.exe that contains a list of items. When the user clicks on the item, the program needs to start up 2.exe and load a form that is relevant to the item, i.e. it can be a different form-name for each item. The name of the form is stored in the database. How do I load the form programmatically after starting up 2.exe without loading ALL the forms in 2.exe? Also, I will need to pass an unique identifier to that form.
Example: The to-do item is 'Check dog name', the form name is 'frm_Dog', and the dog's identifier is 123. When the user clicks on 'Check dog name' in 1.exe, 1.exe fetches the name of the form, starts 2.exe, loads the frm_Dog-form and passes 123 to it, thereby populating the details of the dog on the form.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I didn't know where to start. I assume that it would be something like Dim NewForm as new <formname>, but cannot figure out what the syntax must be.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are 2 applications, the one calling the other.

Comment: The proposed answer will not be able to address my problem :(